# Highest bite force of a wolf?

Tags: bio-mechanics

Some sites say wolves can bite around 400 psi. But this site claims that when facing a peril they can deliver upto 1200 ?**https://plexidors.com/myths-around-dog-bite-force/**(skip to the **'How does that measure compared to cousins in the wild?'** portion to save time)
  -That's a huge range, and could in theory put them on par with big cats.Is what the site says true? 
-I looked online extensively in the internet but I only came across a reddit post where they discuss this and it wasn't conclusive.Why is there a maximum bite force of other animals like crocodiles,gorillas,hyenas etc but not for wolves?

Comment: @Specter writes about other units: PSI (pounds per square inch), but I don't know how it counts to N (newton).

Answer (score 4):

> The range from mean to maximum of wolve's bite force is huge.

Is it really? According to this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masticatory_force#Forces) page, [(Scully, C. (2003). Oxford Handbook of Applied Dental Sciences. p. 151)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masticatory_force#cite_note-Scully_2003-1) claims that human masticatory forces range from 70 N to 700 N. Also, [(Kim et al., 2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5932386/) claims that domestic dogs have a bite force of (147-3417) N, so I don't think it's too implausible for wolves to have the value of (774-2255) N of wolves that [@Olga_Swider](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/47445/olga-%C5%9Awider) claims. We see also, on Table 4 on p. 550 of [(Eng et al., 2013)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6ab9/3067f8479b1f6539eab0809b8ebea969ce51.pdf), the estimated maximum bite force (MBF) spread over the $M^2$ area of the jaw. Eng claims that Gorillas and Chimpanzees have MBFs of 3200 N and 1800 N respectively. I think there's quite a large degree of control of masticatory muscles, which wouldn't make it too surprising that you can have a large range of forces.

> This range of wolves' bite forces could put them on par with big cats.

According to p. 621 of [(Wroe et al., 2005)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1564077/pdf/rspb20042986.pdf), lions have a bite force of around 1768 N, while tigers have a bite force of 1525 N. So, it seems that wolves have a significantly smaller mean bite force than big cats. But bear in mind that while dogs and wolves might have a fairly similar jaw size, lions jaws are much larger so their bite force is spread over a much greater area. So exercise caution when comparing them. Similarly, note that PSI is a unit of pressure (force over area), while newtons are a unit of force.

> Why isn't there a maximum bite force for wolves?

Says who? Of course there's a maximum. Wolves can't make arbitrarily large forces with their mouths, that's physically impossible.

Comment: I did not carry out these tests. I gave the data after literature. In addition, the values given refer to the **mean**. In another chart, in the second item I cited, it can be read that the "maximum **estimated** bite force" does not exceed 3000 N.

Comment: By the way: I do not think that we can measure the maximum bite strength. You will not get the animal to do it. Only estimation remains.

Comment: @Olga I never said you recorded it, I said you **claimed** it. Also, it's redundant whether the second paper is claiming that "the value is 2255 N" or "the value is estimated as 2255 N"; it's the same effect. There's tonnes of stuff in science that you can't measure directly but have to estimate.

Comment: Re "dogs and wolves might have a fairly similar jaw size", that depends on the breed of dog.  A malamute or husky might have a similar jaw size to a wolf, but a Pekinese or an Irish Wolfhound?  Which probably accounts for the wide variation in dog bite force cited.

Comment: @Jam - You wrote that you doubt the presented results. I just made it clea,r that it was difficult for me to discuss it, because I did not estimate or measure it. Have a nice day...

Answer (score 1):

In this article ([Bite forces and evolutionary adaptation to feeding ecology in Carnivores](https://doi.org/10.1890/0012-9658(2007)88[347:BFAEAT]2.0.CO;2)) they say, that bite forces of wolf (Canis lupus) is 774 N. Literature ([Maximum estimated bite force, skull morphology, and primary prey size in North American Carnivores](https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk1/tape2/PQDD_0014/MQ61307.pdf)) gives that: "the wolf had a mean maximum
estimated bite force of 2255 N".